# Facebook app creating a second group

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm creating groups with my FB App and invite users to my App group, everything goes ok the first time. When I try to create another group I got the following error:
{"(OAuthException - #4009) (#4009) This application cannot add more groups until it has more users"}

"...Until it has more users"?
Is there any limit for the groups that we can create?

When I delete the first group and after that create other group, everything works ok.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you found any solutions ?

Answer (score 3):

The number of groups that your app can create is limited by the number of active users your app has.

Either add additional developer accounts to your app (so that they can become 'active users') or try adding some test users to do the same.